# Retrieving MAX(date) value from joined table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, greatest-n-per-group

I need help on a very basic SQL join concept, that I just can't seem to get right.

I have an employee table and a position table.  The employee table is like so:

```
EmpID   Name
1       Jane Jones
2       Bob Smith
3       Jim Adams
```

The position table is like this:

```
PosID   EmpID        Position   DateFilled
1       1            Sales      1/2/2012
2       2            HR         4/5/2013
3       2            Mgmnt      6/1/2014
4       2            Sr. Mgmnt  7/5/2015
5       3            IT Support 4/6/2014
6       3            IT Devel.  5/11/2015
```

How can I get the following output:

```
EmpID   Name        Position    DateFilled
1       Jane Jones  Sales       1/2/2012
2       Bob Smith   Sr. Mgmnt   7/5/2015
3       Jim Adams   IT Devel.   5/11/2015
```

So, in other words, how do I join to get only the record with the max DateFilled column from the position table to join with the corresponding record in the employee table?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, I am stuck revising an Oracle view that uses the old Oracle right join syntax (WHERE e.EmpId = p.EmpID (+) ), so I need the answer to work in that method of joining tables.

Comment: Rewriting Oracle's `(+)` syntax to an outer join is a completely different questions which has been asked many times before. Just search this site for "oracle outer join"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT e.EmpID, e.Name, p.Position, p.DateFilled
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT EmpID, Position, DateFilled,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID 
                             ORDER BY DateFilled DESC) AS rn        
   FROM position
) p ON e.EmpID = p.EmpID AND p.rn = 1
```

Comment: This looks right, but I am stuck revising an Oracle view that uses the old Oracle right join syntax (where e.EmpId = p.EmpID (+) ).  I can't seem to make this concept work within that syntax.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [`MAX() KEEP ( DENSE_RANK [FIRST|LAST] ... )`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions071.htm#i1000905) like this:

```
SELECT e.EmpId,
       e.Name,
       p.position,
       p.datefilled
FROM   employee e
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT EmpID,
                MAX( Position ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY DateFilled ) AS Position,
                MAX( DateFilled ) AS DateFilled
         FROM   position
         GROUP BY EmpID
       ) p
       ON ( e.EmpId = p.EmpID );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select temp.EmpID,(select position from Position where PosID =temp.PosID) position,DateFilled,Name from 
    (select EmpID,max(PosID) PosID,max(DateFilled) DateFilled 
     from position group by EmpID ) temp
    inner join employee  emp on emp.EmpID =temp.EmpID
```